# Junit Test for a Method that fills an Array and counts the items it cant fill in

Tags: java, junit5

i have the following method and need a Junit Test for it, but dont know how to start.i Hope that someone can help me.

```java
package edu.hm.cs.swe2.shoppingmall;

public class ShoppingMall {

    protected Shop[] shops;

    public ShoppingMall(int shopCount) {
        if (shopCount < 1 || shopCount > 10) {
            shopCount = 10;
        }
        this.shops = new Shop[shopCount];
    }

    public int size() {
        return shops.length;
    }

    public int addShops(Shop... shopsToAdd) {
        int notAddedShops = 0;
        int addedShops = 0;

        for (Shop shop : shopsToAdd) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= shops.length - 1; i++) {
                if (shops[i] == null) {
                    shops[i] = shop;
                    addedShops++;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (addedShops <= shopsToAdd.length) {
                notAddedShops = shopsToAdd.length - addedShops;
            }
        }
        return notAddedShops;
    }
```

Comment: Hello, to write a test you have to specify the input and the result you expect once it ends,  you can add them to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So normally you would take look at the class to see what it does.  Apparently you have some kind of arrayList implementation with Shops. You are able to add shops to it.

The ShoppingMall is created with an initial size. You should test that. Test what happens if you call the constructor with an negative number or a very big number for example. Does the code do what you expect is should do ?

next, the addShops function has some logic you should test.

Take a break to think of some scenario's where it might not work. What do you expect to happen ?  You can for example try to add more shops to the ShoppingMall than allowed. What should happen? Which shops should be added and which not ? What will the method return ?